# How does this return statement with two recursive calls work?

Tags: c, recursion

I'm trying to understand this binomial coefficient recursion code in C.

```
int binomial(int n, int m){
    if(m == n){
        return 1;
    }
    else if (m == 0){
        return 1;
    }
    else if (m>n){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        return binomial(n-1,m-1) + binomial(n-1,m);
    }
}
```

I understand everything besides the final line return binomial(n-1,m-1) + binomial(n-1,m);. If anyone is able to explain what is happening I'd appreciate it. I know that actually understanding what the code is doing helps in improving your coding ability so that's why I wanna know.

Comment: A decent explanation of this can be found on Wikipedia under 'Binomial coefficient'. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient). Here is a link to the equation: https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/82edaea83157132aadd2a0ad1e481bfcf6791653

Comment: If you longhand a binomial series expansion, what does it look like? Yeah, kinda like that.

Comment: Have a look at Pascal's Triangle  , where you can see the binomial coeficients laid out in a structure -- and each one is the sum of the two above it.  `n` is the row and `m` is the "column" (if the leftmost of each row is column 0).

Comment: With a little algebra, you can prove that the statement is true; that is, that binomial(n, m) = binomial(n-1, m) + binomial(n-1, m-1) (when m>0 and n>=m). That line of code is what lets the function recurse down to n=m=0.

Answer (score 0):

Following are common definition of Binomial Coefficients :

1. A binomial coefficients C(n, k) can be defined as the coefficient of X^k in the expansion of (1 + X)^n.
2. A binomial coefficients C(n, k) also gives the number of ways, disregarding order, that k objects can be chosen from among n objects; more formally, the number of k-element subsets (or k-combinations) of an n-element set.